# Unable to use terraform's remote exec syntax to customize VM on proxmox

Tags: linux, terraform, centos, infrastructure-as-code, proxmox

I recently encountered some problems when writing a script for Terrafrom automation.

In my case VM is using proxmox platform, not cloud platform
So I use Telmate/proxmox as my mod for creating VMs(CentOS7)

The VM builds smoothly, but when I want to customize the VM(CentOS7), there are some problems

There is an inline usage in terraform’s remote exec Provisioner.
According to the official documentation, this usage applies to line-by-line instructions

I followed this step and used it on my Provision script, the script did execute normally, and it also spawned the VM and executed the installation script.

The content of the install script is

```
yum -y install <something package>
install web service
copy web.conf, web program to /path/to/dir
restart web service
```

But the most important service is not up, but when I start the command in the script via SSH to the VM, the service is normal. That is, this cannot be achieved through terraform’s remote exec

So I want to ask if terraform is not suitable for customizing some services, such as web server, etc.? Only suitable for generating some resources such as VM?

And another custom script needs to be done using such as ansbile?

here is sample code

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "yum -y install tar",
      "tar -C / -xvf /tmp/product.tar",
      "sh install.sh",
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You can do what ever  you want with TF. However, you question lacks details and is unclear. You haven't even explained what OS are you using, what exactly is `install.sh`, are there any errors?

Comment: I use terraform to build a Linux VM on proxmox. And use remote-exec to execute script, install services such as web server, and enable these services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to understand this matter later, I am not sure if there is a problem with the program written by the developer or other reasons. Anyway, I can't enable the service (process) via script. But it is possible to enable the service by rebooting and using the built-in system service (systemctl).